# How to insertElementAt, arraylist java

Tags: java

We're suppose to do tutorial before class but im having trouble with one questions. I have to complete this code:

```
    public class Tester2 {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee[] list = new Employee[5];
        Employee emp1 = new Employee("Harvey", 75000.00);
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("Donna", 10000.00);
        Employee emp3 = new Employee("Mike", 40000.00);
        addElement(emp1, list);
        addElement(emp2, list);
        addElement(emp3, list);
        insertElementAt(new Employee("Jessica", 100000.00), list, 1);
        displayElements(list); // Line 1
        removeElementAt(list, 0);
        System.out.println("");
        displayElements(list); // Line 2
      }
      public static void displayElements(Employee[] list) {
         for (Employee element: list) {
           if (element != null) {
             System.out.println(element.getName() + " RM " +
             element.getSalary());
           }
         }
      }
```

`public static void addElement(Employee emp, Employee[] list) {
              for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
                if (list[i] == null) {
                   list[i] = emp;
                   break;
                }
              }
            }`

```
        public static void insertElementAt(Employee emp, Employee[] list,   
        int pos) {
          // Complete the body!
        }
     public static void removeElementAt(Employee[] list, int pos) {
        // Complete the body!
     }
 }
```

im not sure what im suppose to put at void insertElementAt. i thought this:

```
    `emp.setname("Jessica");
    emp.setEmpCode(100000.00);
    list.add(emp);`
```

but then i saw this line :insertElementAt(new Employee("Jessica", 100000.00), list, 1); and i think theres a different way but i dont know. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by incrementing and decrementing the array based on position of insert and remove in a new array and then copy the array.

Below is the code which worked

```
public static void insertElementAt(Employee emp, Employee[] list,   
        int pos) {
    Employee[] nlist = new Employee[5];
    for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        if(i==pos){
            nlist[i]=emp;
        }else if(i>pos){
            nlist[i]=list[i-1];
        }else{
            nlist[i]=list[i];
        }
      }
    System.arraycopy(nlist, 0, list, 0, 5);
}
public static void removeElementAt(Employee[] list, int pos) {
    Employee[] nlist = new Employee[5];
    for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        if(i>=pos){
            if(i<4){
                nlist[i]=list[i+1];;
            }
        }else{
            nlist[i]=list[i];
        }
    }
    System.arraycopy(nlist, 0, list, 0, 5);
}
```